# Reset forloop counter in django template nested for loop

Tags: django

How to reset the forloop counter in django template?

This is my current QuerySets:

```
context['major'] = Major.objects.all().filter(is_active=True).order_by('id')
context['minor'] = Minor.objects.all().filter(is_active=True).order_by('id')
```

And this is my Models:

```
class Major(models.Model):
    major_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', null=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.major_name

class Minor(models.Model):
    major_name = models.ForeignKey(Major, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    minor_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', null=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.minor_name
```

So I have something like this:

```
{% for major in majors %}
    {% for minor in minors %}
        {% if minor.major_name == major %}
            {{forloop.counter}} {{minor}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Current output:

```
major1
    1 minor1
    2 minor2
major2
    3 minor3
    4 minor4
    5 minor5
    ...
```

I want it to display something like:

```
major1
    1 minor1
    2 minor2
major2
    1 minor3
    2 minor4
    3 minor5
    ...
```

Comment: Can you add the `majors` and `minors` models and querysets to your question? It may be easier to change the way you define or iterate over your data as "resetting" the forloop counter like you ask is not trivial/possible

Comment: Added my querysets.

Comment: I also tried adding the {%with%} tag inside template but I dont think I can increment the variable from with tag

Comment: Can you add the models too?

Comment: Added it too...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you are trying to achieve is displaying all `Minor` instances related to a `Major` instance filtered and indexed.

Rather than looping over all filtered `Minor` instances again and again, you can pass a [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) object to [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to add a filter to the related queryset (`major.minor_set`) for the reverse relationship and then loop over that

```
context['majors'] = Major.objects.filter(
    is_active=True
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('minor_set', queryset=Minor.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('id'))
).order_by('id')
```

Then in the template

```
{% for major in majors %}
    {% for minor in major.minor_set.all %}
        {{ forloop.counter }} {{ minor }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I got an error `minor_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()` after implementing.

Comment: and django is pointing to for major in majors.

Comment: Is the `Minor` -> `Major` foreign key exactly as described in your question? It does not have a `related_name` so the reverse relation must be named `minor_set`?

Comment: Minor -> Major ForeignKey yes. But no related name.

Comment: Running a test locally using your models works fine for me. What is the full error message? Does it start with `Cannot find 'minor_set' on Major object`?

Comment: Sorry I am new to the django so my knowledge is lacking

Comment: `cannot find minor_set in major object`  'minor_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

Comment: Given the models in your question there will 100% be a `minor_set` attribute on each `Major` object. If there is not, then there is something else wrong with your model(s). As an experiment, what happens if you run `Major.objects.first().minor_set.all()`?

Comment: no object minor set. btw. where did you come up with the minor_set? is it a variable? or was it based on the current model? I had to downsize my code since it is complex.

Comment: When you have a `ForeignKey` from one model to an other: a "reverse manager" attribute is added to the "other" model that can be used to query all related objects, by default it's named `<model name lowercase>_set`. In your case a `ForeignKey` from `Minor` to `Major` will result in a reverse manager attribute added to `Major` named `minor_set`. Passing the parameter `related_name` to the `ForeignKey` can override this default https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I just blindly followed the code and just realized what this minor_set is. The actual name is longer that is why there was an error.

Comment: Everything works now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad you found the solution